# Jquery Mobile - Slow with page transitions

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using jquery mobile Im using persistant header and footer. The footer nav has tabs and when you click a tab it loads a page via ajax. The problem is the transition from one page to another, which is ajax loading a div with the specific id, is very slow. It takes 2-5 seconds for the page transition to happen. when I click a tab it highlights a different color but nothing happens, then a few seconds later the transition happens. Sometimes if you click to fast the layout breaks and the footer dissappears. Im doing this on an ipad with the latest version of jquery mobile. Is jquery mobile just really slow? Will waiting till ios5 make all the difference?

**UPDATE**

Here is a snippet of code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <a href="#dialog" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="check">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li data-role="list-divider"><span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
      <li>
        <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
        <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
        <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
      </li>
</ul>
  <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-id="myfooter" data-position="fixed"> 
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="b">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="reverse slide" id="chat" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="email" data-icon="custom">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="skull" data-icon="custom">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <a href="#dialog" data-transition="slidedown" data-icon="check">Add</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li data-role="list-divider"><span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
      <li>
        <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
        <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
        <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
      </li>
</ul>
  <div data-role="footer" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-id="myfooter" data-position="fixed"> 
    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="b">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1" data-transition="reverse slide" id="chat" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="email" data-icon="custom">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="skull" data-icon="custom">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: provide some code which shows what you are really doing? how is the anchor provided? did you use page definitions to load pages? add some code, would be helpful..

Comment: Try removing the page transition animation and see if it loads the page any faster.  That will narrow down whether its the ajax request taking forever or the animation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes if you click to fast the layout breaks and the footer
>   dissappears:

This is a problem is adressed already here, did not find a solution yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484522/jquerymobile-click-on-background-fires-event-header-footer-data-position-fixe

About the loading time, it really is strange, try to focus the error with removing parts of your code and narrow down where and why the long loading time is occurring... hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the scrollview plugin with jquery mobile as well. Would that have any effect on loading between pages?

Comment: Actually just removed the scrollview plugin and not much faster. Basically I have the tabs in the footer, when I click to go to a different tab it sits there for a few seconds. Then the page transition happens, in this case a slide. Then I click to the previous tab in the footer and again it hangs for a few seconds then transitions back to the previous tab. This not only looks/feels clunky it leaves open for people who double click and when that happens weird things happen like half the page is gone or the footer dissappears or nothing happens at all.

Comment: try to narrow down where the error is coming from (exlude step by step parts of your code), in my opinion its not a normal JQM behavior. The IPad itsself is running normal? Anything in background which makes it slow or makes it wait?

Comment: I tried stripping it down as much as possible, still same issue. I have an ipad1 and a ipad2 and both continue to have the same issue.

Comment: Any luck? We have the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem. Disabling the fancy screen transitions fixed it for me.

To do this universally:

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
```

Comment: Performance was improved drastically with RC3. Upgrading Jquery Mobile will also help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the same ids multiple times. For me it caused similar problems. Try to remove/change the duplicated ids.

For example you simply copy-pasted this section in order to duplicate it on the second page:

```
<li><a href="#page1" data-transition="reverse slide" id="chat" data-icon="custom" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2" data-transition="slide" id="email" data-icon="custom">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3" data-transition="slide" id="skull" data-icon="custom">Link 3</a></li>
```